# RoundRobin by Time Window

Tags: date, round-robin

I'm looking for a system that stores **timestamped values** and remove automatically the ones that are **older than specific time window**.

Something like a *RoundRobin* system but, as long I understand, *RoundRobin* is based in an **specific amount** of records and removing as much old ones as much new ones are coming.

In this system can be **any amount** of records and just removing the ones that are older than an specific time lapsus.

One approximation can be a system where every record has a Timeout live like:

```
console.append "key", { :value => "value1", :timeout => 10.minutes_in_the_future }
console.append "key", { :value => "value2", :timeout => 10.minutes_in_the_future }
console.append "key", { :value => "value3", :timeout => 10.minutes_in_the_future }
```

And somehow the system is in charge to remove any expired record.

The system can be based in any high-performance storage system (Redis, Memcache, ...)

I'm not looking for a full detailed explanation implementation just some kind of inspiration or any related article or already existing system so I'm not *reinventing the wheel*.

Comment: What are you working in? A database?

Comment: @Celada: I have added more info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Memcache aprox

In the office we are studying this aprox:

### Preconditions

- The *time window* is **10 minutes**.
- We only need to know **the amount** of records and not the values.
- We can live with **not very accurate** solution.

### Implementation

1. Create a new *key* every minute like: `mykey_<Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M")>`.
2. Give them a *expire time* of **10 minutes**.
3. Every time we want to add a record we `incr` the key for our **actual minute**.
4. To calculate the *time window value* we get the values of the **10 keys** for the last 10 minutes and **sum them**.

### Cons

- We can not store real values but only **one accumulate**.
- When every *1 minute key* is expired the total value **fluctuates suddenly**.